# Can boost::program_options Use A Delimiter Other Than "-"?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I am using boost::program_options like this:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Options");
desc.add_options()
  ("help,?", "Show Options")
  ("capture-file,I", po::value<string>(), "Capture File")   
  ("capture-format,F", po::value<string>()->default_value("pcap"), "Capture File Format")
  ("output-file,O", po::value<string>()->default_value("CONOUT$"), "Output File");

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av).options(desc)./*positional(pd).*/run(), vm);
```

If I pass the command line parameter `-I hithere` it works, but it I pass `/I hithere` boost throws a `boost::bad_any_cast` with a `what()` of " failed conversion using boost::any_cast".

Is it possible to use program_options to parse either `/`-delimitted or `-`-delimitted options?  Bonus question, can it be configured so that `/` and `-` set the same option, but are binary opposites of each other?  For example, `/verbose` might mean verbose logging while `-verbose` might mean less verbose logging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `/` and `-`, use `command_line_parser`'s `style()` method with the appropriate combination of [style_t](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html) flags.  For example:

```
po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av)
    .options(desc)
    .style(po::command_line_style::default_style
        | po::command_line_style::case_insensitive
        | po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short
        | po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise)
    /*.positional(pd)*/
    .run(), vm);
```

(`allow_long_disguise` lets `/` start a long option.)

You could probably make `/` and `-` opposites by adding your own [additional parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id1421528); however, this would be very nonstandard and therefore potentially confusing to end users, so I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: You're probably right.  Is it possible to determine which delimiter was used after the call to `store`?

Comment: Unless you're using your own additional parser, I don't think so.

Comment: OK, that was a bonus question anyway. :)